# Facebook User Authentication iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, parse-platform

I get this error when the user tries to sign up using Facebook but the safari view pops up and the user signs in. I check the back end and there is in fact a new user. Is this going to be an issue?

```
2015-03-27 23:41:13.683 CSUsedBooks[698:10815] FBSDKLog: Cannot use the Facebook app or Safari to authorize, fb484698225002234 is not registered as a URL Scheme
User signed up and logged in through Facebook!
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the configuration on your .plist (supporting files of your project)?

Find the **.plist** file in the Supporting Files folder in your XCode Project.

1. In the **.plist** create a key called **FacebookAppID** with String as Type and copy your AppID **484698225002234** as a string to the value field.
2. Next create a key called **FacebookDisplayName** with String as Type and copy your App Name (**${YOUR APP NAME HERE}**) as a string to the value field.
3. Finally, create a key called **URL types** with Array as Type with a dictionary as its only child. That dictionary needs one array as child called **URL Schemes**. The child of that array is a String with **fb484698225002234** as a value.

check: https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/